# Link with image on popup don't work in chrome extention

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Link with image on popup don't work.
For example, it is like this code.

```
<a href="https://test.com/"><img src="test.png"></a>
```

I deal with this problem by "onclick" on Javascript.

Is there good way to work link with image normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are **[not allowed](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution)** to have inline event handler, you can add an external JS file (e.g. popup.js) and register listeners for the `click` event (using `addEventListener()`). E.g.:

**popup.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <a href="https://test.com/"><img src="test.png"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    /* Get all images that are direct descendants of anchor elements */
    var imgsInAs = document.querySelectorAll('a > img');

    /* For each such img element... */
    [].slice.call(imgsInAs).forEach(function(img) {

        /* ...register a listener for the 'click' event that... */
        img.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {

            /* ...simulates a 'click' on its parent-node 
             * (i.e. the anchor element) */
            evt.preventDefault();
            img.parentNode.click();
        });
    });
});
```